# Is there any bean created for spring @propertySource annotation

Tags: spring

I have used spring @propertysource annotation to load properties file in my spring boot project . I just need to know is there any bean created for this annotation when application gets started

Answer (score 0):

`@PropertySource` annotation is used to let spring-boot know the location of the properties required by your application. It will not create any bean.